# Error when clipping raster with vector layer

Tags: qgis, raster, clip

I'm trying to clip a raster (GeoTIFF) with a vector layer in QGIS (version 2.18).

I get the error "*ERROR 1: Attempt to create 0x0 dataset is illegal,sizes must be larger than zero.*" when I changed the resolution (x and y resolution = 250 meters, the same resolution of my input raster).

However, when I choose for "keep the resolution of the input raster", the program script indicates a resolution "-tr 0.002083333 0.002083333" and gives a clipped raster with only missing values ("nan").

My raster and vector polygon have the same coordinate reference system (WGS 84).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reproject your vector and raster data into a projection that uses meter or feet units depending on your region and try the clip tool again. WGS84 can cause a problem because the pixel sizes of the raster data are in decimal degree. Using a projection of meter unit, for example UTM, can solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you, resampling to another projection (UTM) did indeed work.

Comment: @user132304 Glad it worked :)